# Getting xml for a playlist - custom spotify playlist

Tags: spotify

I am looking to create a custom spotify playlist rather than use the generator via the website. I need a way of grabbing this xml, rather like the lookup and search facilities that the webAPI provide. I have tried to use a playlist spotifyURI with the lookup functionality but it doesnt seem to work.

e.g.

http://ws.spotify.com/lookup/1/?uri=spotify:user:XXX:playlist:YYY

However, using this just gives me the following error :

"You hit the rate limit, wait 10 seconds and try again"

I don't think I have really hit the hitrate, I only tried it a few times.

If this isnt the way to go, what other options are there ? libSpotify ? This seems like rather a bigger solution for just getting some xml for a playlist.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web API doesn't support playlist lookup at all. If you want to find playlist data, you'd have to use libspotify.